# Mount points overlapped

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, xfs

I have a VM with RHEL 6 where I have several disks with their respective mount points, they are in xfs and each one has a label which is declared in the fstab for each mount point

It happens that the storage VM was migrated and to reboot seems to be that the mount points overlapped, because I see the same information repeated in two mount points and there is a disk that is not mounted.

I wanted to know if the information of that disk that was not mounted was lost or can I try to mount it on another new directory to verify without risk.

Comment: You can mount the disk, and if you are concerned about data loss, mount it read-only. But I would first check for relevant messages in the system log. What does the storage VM have to do with this? What do you mean with "the same information repeated in two mount points"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drives are simply not mounted at the correct location, there should be no modification or data loss at all. However, you could modify that fstab file to ensure that the mount won't fail again by configuring [unique UUID for each partition](https://linuxhint.com/mount_partition_uuid_label_linux/). To do so, use [bklid](https://linux.die.net/man/8/blkid) to identify the properties of each partition and paste them accordingly in fstab.